Cannot find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle
First of all, I decided to make my project with only UIKit.
So I deleted 'Main' storyboard, Info.plist->Storyboard name, and Main storyboard file base name->Main. And I edited SceneDelegate.
So now I can display the single viewControllers, but when I try to set 'UITabBarController' to rootViewController, It cause this error(title).
I tried to make UITabBarController in ViewController, UITabBarController in SceneDelegate and some more.
// BackgroundViewController for the rootViewController

import UIKit

class BackgroundViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let backgroundTabBarController = UITabBarController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        createTabBar()
    }
}

extension BackgroundViewController {
    private func createTabBar() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(backgroundTabBarController.view)
        
        let firstViewController = BookSearchViewController()
        let secondViewController = MainViewController()
        let thirdViewController = UserStatusViewController()
        let lastViewController = OrderViewController()
        
        firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle"))
//        firstViewController.tabBarItem.tag = 0
        secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Main", image: UIImage(systemName: "house.fill"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "house"))
//        secondViewController.tabBarItem.tag = 1
        thirdViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "My", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.fill"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "person"))
//        thirdViewController.tabBarItem.tag = 2
        lastViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Order", image: UIImage(systemName: "menucard.fill"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "menucard"))
//        lastViewController.tabBarItem.tag = 3
        
        backgroundTabBarController.viewControllers = [firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController, lastViewController]
        backgroundTabBarController.selectedViewController = secondViewController
    }
}

// SceneDelegate

import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        window?.rootViewController = BackgroundViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

// Error code

Thread 1: "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/[MyDesktopName]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[ApplicationName]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/[ApplicationName]/BTY.app> (loaded)"

But anyone of this solve the problem.
How can I make UITabBarController to rootViewController?

Make UITabBarController in SceneDelegate
Make new UIViewController that have UITabBarController and set to rootViewController
Set ViewControllers with 'UINavigationController(rootViewController:)'
Present UITabBarController from other viewController


Do a global search of your project for "Main". Somewhere you missed a reference. None of the code you posted is relevant to the error.

Beyond that, your BackgroundViewController class should be a UITabBarController. It should not be a UIViewController.

Should I delete @main in AppDelegate? Without that, I don't have any other options.
Also, I already have UITabBarController named BTYTabBarController and tried to make it rootViewController, it didn't work.

No, leave @main. Do a case-sensitive search on "Main". If there's nothing found, including in the target's Build Settings, do a clean build.

I couldn't find any suspicious 'main' contained syntax.
And I found AppKit Main Storyboard File Base Name, Main Nib File Base Name, UIKit Main Storyboard File Base Name, 'Privacy - Access to a File Provide Domain Usage Description` in Build Settings.
Any text isn't there, but I should erase them?
